# Efficient computation of Jacobsthal matrix / quadratic character in GF(q)

Tags: algorithms, galois-theory, finite-fields, quadratic-residues

Is there an efficient algorithm to compute the quadratic character $\chi$ on GF($q$) in order to get the [Jacobsthal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_matrix)
$$
  J_{i,j} = \chi(i-j) = \begin{cases} ~0 & \rm if & i = j\\ ~1 &\rm if& i-j ~~\text{ is a square in GF}(q)\\ -1&\rlap{\rm otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
where $i,j$ run over the elements of GF($q$)? (Unfortunately, when $q=p^n$ with $n>1$, one cannot simply take $i,j\in\mathbb Z$ and check for quadratic residues modulo $q$. In particular, the $J$ matrix isn't even circular in that case.)

So, I'd like to know whether there's a way to determine whether some $x\in{\rm GF}(q)$ is a square without the need for implementing (full) arithmetic in GF($q$). (If I can compute arbitrary products in GF($q$), I can obviously simply compute the set $S=\{x\cdot x~;~ x\in {\rm GF}(q)\}$ of all squares, and check whether the element $i-j$ is in $S$. But implementing general multiplication in GF($q$) is nontrivial. (To start with, I have to find an irreducible polynomial $P\in{\rm GF}(p)_n[X]$ of degree $n$ over GF($p$)...) Is it possible to compute the list of squares in a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Normally one shouldn't use $i,j$ since they indicate integers while the elements of $GF(q)$ aren't integers.

I don't know if there is a faster method than the one below.

In any case, choose random elements from $GF(q)$ and test them until you find a primitive element $\alpha$ which generates $GF(q)^\ast.$ Let $q=p^n.$

Then list the quadratic residues
$$
L=[\alpha^{2j}:j \in \{0,1,\ldots,(p^n-1)/2\}],
$$
and we will have $\chi(x)=+1$ for $x\in L.$ For $x\in GF(q)^\ast \setminus L$ we will have $\chi(x)=-1.$

Now you need a fast addition (really subtraction) algorithm. One way to obtain this is by using the Zech logarithm (look it up) $Z_\alpha(k)$ defined by
$$
\alpha^{Z_\alpha(k)}=1+\alpha^k, \quad k \in \{0,\ldots,p^n-2\}
$$
with $Z_\alpha(0)=-\infty.$

If $p=2,$ then you can implement the subtraction as
$$
x-x'=\alpha^{k}-\alpha^{k'}=\alpha{k}+\alpha^{k'}=
\alpha^k(1+\alpha^{k'-k}=\alpha^{k+Z_{\alpha}(k-k'))
$$
and table lookup in $L$ to compute $\chi(x-x').$

For odd characteristic you can define the Zech via $1-\alpha^k$ if you wish, it is a bit simpler.

Comment: I considered using x,y or a,b instead if i,j, but I thought it was better to use i,j **and** write "...run over the elements of GF(q)" to clarify that they are indices of the matrix, which is otherwise not obvious and therefore confusing (since it's quite unusual to have indices other than integers).

Comment: But your answer misses the whole point which is: **how to get the list of quadratic residues?** The question is, **how can you know** (or, *if you have to,* compute) the "squares" (= quadratic residues), in the simplest possible way. You write the even powers of alpha^2k, I think it might be simpler to compute only squares of elements [excluding their opposite]). How to do **that** in a simple way is the question. If I can compute 
alpha^2k, then it's trivial to compute squares.  For addition and subtraction, which you explain, it's trivial (component-wise, viewing GF(q) as GP(p)^n).